# How to Auto fill the datagridview cell value with 0.00 in .NET if cell is blank or null vlaue?

Tags: datagridview

I am very new in this platform.Please help me out.Currently i am working on Journal Voucher under an accounting project.
Here is my table(DataGridView):
[journal voucher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBV0R.jpg)

I want make it like this:
if i am giving any value in debit "0.00" automatically should come in Credit side and if am giving any value in Credit side, debit side value should be "0.00

Comment: Without more info I am guessing you may want to look at the grids `CellValueChanged` event. [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netcore-3.1) … In is unclear what you want to do if “both” cells are empty.

Comment: Sir, if both cells are empty it should give an error message that it can't save or Debit and Credit cannot be Nill Value.

Comment: From your comment… _”if both cells are empty it should give an error message that it can't save or Debit and Credit cannot be Nill Value.”_ … I assume you have a “save” `Button` or some mechanism that signals that the user wants to “save” the data in the grid. In this “save” portion of the code you could check for these invalid values “before” saving.

Comment: If you want to “validate” this data while the user enters data directly into the grid, then you will need to wire up numerous grid events to prevent the user from “leaving” the new row in an invalid state. I suggest that instead of allowing the user to add rows directly into the grid… use a separate `Form` to allow the user enter the new row data. This separate form will make validating the data much easier.